# How can I send email to email contact in rails app form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I want to have a form in my app where a logged in user can input their friend's email addresses, click send, and it will send out an automated email to the email addresses that they entered into the form. Here is what I have so far. I get unitialized constant when I click on the button to take you to the form so I don't know what else isn't working too.

invitations_controller.rb

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
end

def create
     @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
     @invitation.invited_by = current_user.invitation_token # set the sender to the current user
     if @invitation.save
      Mailer.invitation(@invitation, new_user_path(:invite_token =>  @invitation.invited_by)).deliver #send the invite data to our mailer to deliver the email
     else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to root_url
     end
    end
   end
```

mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "donotreply@mysite.com"

 def invitation(invitation, signup_url)
  subject    'Invitation'
  recipients @recipient_email
  from       'donotreply@mysite.com'
  body       :invitation => invitation, :signup_url => signup_url
  invitation.update_attribute(:sent_at, Time.now)
 end
end
```

invitation.html.erb

```
Mailer#invitation
You are invited to join our beta!

<%= signup_url(@invitation.invited_by) %>
```

new.html.erb (invitation form)

```
    <%= simple_form_for @invitation, :url => new_invitation_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :invitation_token, :value => @invitation.invited_by %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
    <% end %>
```

I can't even get to the invitation form because I get the uninitialized constant error. So for all I know it works beyond that. Help please

Comment: Which constant is uninitialised?

Comment: uninitialized constant InvitationsController::Invitation

Comment: Do you have an `Invitation` model?

Comment: No. I take it by that comment I need one? I made a mailer for confirmation email which I got working. I don't have a model for that. But for some reason, take user input and sending the email is proving more difficult to me than sending an automatic email on user signup.

Comment: Of course you need a table of invitations, you are saying `Invitation.new ....` meaning you are initializing an invitation object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `Invitation` model.

```
rails generate model Invitation invited_by:string sent_at:timestamp
```

[See the getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-post-model)

Comment: Did that. Now I'm getting undefined method `email' in the new.html.erb

Comment: You need to add an `email` field to the `Invitation` model

Comment: Ok so I can go to the /invitations/new page where the form is, enter an email and click submit. In the console I get 'Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, invitation, commit'. Here is my current code https://gist.github.com/th3cuda/274f31bccf8df00593eb

Comment: See the part about `permit` in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller

Comment: Ok got past that but all it does now is redirect back to an empty form. The log shows it capturing the form info but then does nothing with it; store in the invitation table, or send the email

Comment: @user3443619 Follow a tutorial or something. This isn't the place to learn the absolute basics.